# Can anyone recommend a text messaging service for sending alerts and notices from an Oracle database on Linux?

Tags: linux, oracle, messaging

We're investigating ways to alert users of application errors out-of-hours. Has anyone used a Linux-based text messaging (phone) service for sending out alerts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My cell provider has an email address (in my case, [phonenumber]@mobile.mycingular.com) where I can email stuff and it comes as an sms to my phone.  I just send alerts to it.

Comment: I'll look into this as an option. Would work really well. There's becoming less and less of a difference between receiving emails and receiving texts.

Comment: This is an option almost all, if not all, of the major cellular providers have.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Skype4Py](https://developer.skype.com/wiki/Skype4Py), will work anywhere. You can either integrate in your scripts, or use [command line utility](http://www.oberle.org/blog/2007/06/11/sending-sms-with-skype-on-linux/).

Comment: This looks like a really nice and simple way to get SMS text messaging up and running.

Answer (score 2):

i'm using Siemens Cellular Engine TC35 Terminal connected over serial port to linux server. to send SMSes i use [scmxx](http://www.hendrik-sattler.de/scmxx/).

in my case i have [nagios](http://nagios.org) monitoring some servers and custom alerting scripts that dispatch messages to people who are on-call at given time. you can skip this part and just have cron job polling you oracle [ message que ? ]. make sure that no two scmxx are executed at the same time - since one of them will fail to get access to serial port.

you can also talk with your gsm operator - they probably have some sms gateway reachable from internet. i've used such service from polish operator plusgsm - they have web-services api reachable via https. they charge separately for access to the service and per each sms sent.

Answer (score 0):

Using GSM terminal such as TC35 mentioned by pQd gives you the reliability = you can request delivery confirmation receipt and get it only when the SMS is delivered to the user's terminal.
When the shit really hits the fan, you can also dial out to the number and wake up the poor guy...

Sending emails is for sure not reliable and I don't know about Skype.